# While running on Server i am getting HTML code on my browser

Tags: python, html, css, django, python-3.x

When i am running my Django project on local server. It is returning whole html code on webpage.

Like after executing command `python manage.py runserver` and copy and pasting url on browser i am getting whole HTML file code instead element i have used.

My Html file

```
{% extends "wfhApp/base.html" %}
{% block body_block %}

<div class="jumbotron">
  {% if registered %}
  <h1>Thank you for registration</h1>

  {% else %}
  <h1>Register here!</h1>
  <h3>Fill out the form:</h3>

  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" name="" value="Register">
  </form>

  {% endif %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from wfhApp.forms import UserForm

def register(request):

    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data = request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():

            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm

    return render(request, 'wfhApp/registration.html',
                                            {'user_form': user_form},
                                            {'registered': registered})
```

Above is from template inheritance.

Comment: what do you mean "It is returning whole html code on webpage" ??? And where's your view code ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I have added my views.py file. Please check and let me know if there is anything i am missing.

Comment: Well, you still didn't explain what you meant by "It is returning whole html code on webpage".

Comment: Mmm ok I guess I see what's the issue is...

Comment: After running my project on server instead html page with Registration Form in it. I am getting whole HTML code.

Comment: Images of code are not welcomed here but for once a screenshot would have made things clearer ;-) But anyway, problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 101% sure since you didn't really explained what you meant by "It is returning whole html code on webpage" but here:

```
return render(request, 'wfhApp/registration.html',
                                        {'user_form': user_form},
                                        {'registered': registered})
```

you're not correctly passing the template context - or, more exactly, you are passing `{'user_form': user_form}` as the context and `{'registered': registered}` as the response's content_type (which would else be the default "text/html").

What you want is (splitted on two lines for readability):

```
context = {
    'user_form': user_form,
    'registered': registered
    }
return render(request, 'wfhApp/registration.html', context)
```